# Does Mr. Braun still have his secret occupation in the beta world line (1%)?

Tags: steins-gate

We know that FB is Mr. Braun. Now Okabe is in the Beta worldline, and M4, a.k.a. Moeka, is working part-time for Mr. Braun, a.k.a. FB which is very suspicious...
Technically, they are still operating as Rounders, right? It's just they haven't take any actions against the Future Gadgets Lab yet, apart from retrieving the IBN 5100.

Right guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, Yuugo Tennouji (Mr. Braun) still has his *secret job* in the Beta world line after 1% divergence is obtained.

I base this on the wiki entry, which lists Steins; Gate 0 as its source. Here is what the Wiki says about this:

> When 1% Divergence is obtained, Yuugo is seen running his shop, having apparently never worked for SERN in this world line. But as revealed by Steins;Gate 0, he still works for SERN in the Beta Worldline. [Source: Wiki- Yuugo Tennouji](http://steins-gate.wikia.com/wiki/Yuugo_Tennouji)

Edit: The anime adaptation of Zero is greenlit, but there is no broadcast date. I haven't read the Visual Novel.

Wiki page for [Zero](http://steins-gate.wikia.com/wiki/Steins;Gate_0_(Anime_Series)) states,

> The Steins;Gate 0 (シュタインズ・ゲート ゼロ Shutainzu Gēto Zero?) anime is an adaptation of a spin-off visual novel by the same name that is being marketed as a "true sequel" visual novel, as opposed to being a fan disc. However, though **Zero is part of the main canon**, it is narratively not taking place after the true ending of the original story but technically before said ending. Zero is a side story that explores events from the Beta Attractor Field's future that contribute in making the end of the original story possible.

Comment: The fact that he's working for SERN in beta can also be intuited by the fact that Moeka said to be recruited by Tennouji in 2004 while Okabe is in the alpha timeline, but 2004 is before the two timelines diverged (that happened in 2010.).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in @Arcane's answer, **yes**, he is still a Rounder in the Beta world line.

In the Steins;Gate 0 VN, there are multiple world lines in which Okabe and his friends are attacked by various groups/organizations and he ends up turning to Yuugo Tennouji for help,

> blackmailing him into helping by revealing knowledge that he is the leader of the Rounders. Mr. Braun's response confirms that Okabe was correct.

Additionally,

> Moeka is still a Rounder too, though, as long as Okabe and his friends stay away from time travel research, the Rounders have no reason to be interested in them.

Since Okabe never switches out of the Beta world line in this VN, it is safe to assume that Mr. Braun retains his secret occupation in all instances of the Beta world line.